# CakePHP - How to add attributes to individual radio buttons?

Tags: cakephp, radio-button

How do I add individual attributes to radio buttons?  As far as I can tell, CakePHP only allows you to add the same (limited) attributes to all radio buttons in the group.

Any ideas for how to generate this, for example?

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" name="data[MyModel][field]" id="custom-id-1" class="custom-class-1" data-something="test1">
<label for="custom-id-1">Test 1</label>
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" name="data[MyModel][field]" id="custom-id-2" class="custom-class-2" data-something="test2">
<label for="custom-id-2">Test 2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
$options = array('1' => 'Test 1'); <br> $attributes =
array('value'=>'1','class'=>'custom-class-1','id'=>'custom-id-1','data-something'=>'test1');

echo $this->Form->radio('field_name1', $options, $attributes);

---------------------


$options = array('1' => 'Test 2'); <br> $attributes =
array('value'=>'1','class'=>'custom-class-2','id'=>'custom-id-2','data-something'=>'test2');

echo $this->Form->radio('field_name2', $options, $attributes);
```

Answer (score -1):

`echo $this->Form->input('title', array('type' => 'radio', 'class' => 'custom-class', 'atributeName' => 'attributeValue'));`

Comment: Do you have an example that generates a group of radio buttons with the model association? Can you make an example that generates the HTML I posted?